# Javascript function to submit form from browser shortcut

Tags: javascript, form-submit, shortcut

In order to submit several sites on this analysis website : https://www.outiref.fr
I'd like to create a browser shortcut submitting automatically the visiting page to this site.

I have the same shortcut to submit a google search with "site:" :

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://www.google.com/search?tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2000&q=site%3A'+encodeURIComponent(location.href))})();
```

I try to use the same method, but I can not achieve my goal with

```js
javascript:(function(){window.open('https://www.outiref.fr')(
window.location='https://www.outiref.fr')(document.getElementById("audit_uri")(encodeURIComponent(location.href)).InputEvent(document.getElementById("audit_save").submit()))})();
```

Edit: I want to fill up the form, not submitting it.

Comment: Apart from the fact that the JS code is not valid, due to the Same-Origin-Policy you cannot access a window's `document` if you opened a page hosted on a different domain. If the form's method is `GET`, you can compose the URL yourself, but the form in question uses `POST`.

Comment: I'm not a developer so I knew my code could be wrong... but I get your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That not possible. Google provide URL like /search=XXX for launch search directly but not outiref. In outiref the search is only in JS and you can't trigger an element in other site from your website.

And more, outiref only provide an URL with /YOUR_SEARCH but we cannot use that because the page is cached and is generate previously. You can see because in URL of https://www.outiref.fr/audit+test.com+5a7d91599a8a836.php you have a hase in the last part of url and you can't access to https://www.outiref.fr/audit+test.com.php directly.

Comment: Actually my goal is to fill the form with the url i'm visiting... not necessarily submit it !